# Accessing 3 tables from a database in mysql using JPA , springboot in json keys format

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am making a project and almost all the functions are almost complete but now I am stuck at the response part. There are three tables and all having an id as primary not null. I am getting a get request which includes the id. I have to give the data from three tables in mysql containing that id.
The code below is working great with a single table. But I have to show the data from all the three tables.

I tried using @SecondaryTable but all in vain.

Users.java

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name="persons")
@SecondaryTable(name="data")
public class Users {


    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "teamName")
    private String teamName;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private Integer salary;

    @Column(table="data",name="type")
    private String type;

    @Column(table="data",name="value")
    private String value;

    @Column(table="data",name="hints")
    private String u;

}
-----Getters and Setters-----
```

Error

```
2019-06-15 13:10:45.510  INFO 7072 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-06-15 13:10:45.870  INFO 7072 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2019-06-15 13:10:45.968  WARN 7072 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
Sat Jun 15 13:10:45 IST 2019 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun........ Goes on and on
```

The first problem is that I need to show data from three tables. But to make matters worse even the two tables data is getting fetched. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how SQL and JPA works?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli The basics . But not like a pro. Basically, this project was given to me to learn springboot but I am a complete newbie in this.

Comment: My advice.: Read the docs. Take some tutorials or an only course.

Comment: You are creating a new project and you want to use secondary table? Why are you complicating database model while starting from scratch? Have individual tables with individual entity classes with appropriate foreign keys. This way you code is much cleaner.

Comment: @GaneshHoolageri I am forced to make such a project within a fixed deadline even though I don't know anything about it. There is a team of 4 and no knows springboot but we have to make a rest api using it. I am completely stuck right now.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank You. I don't think I can complete a course in such a less amount of time but I would head over to the docs. Thanks